# stop sounds in threads c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, audio

I've got two questions about some problems on this code:

1) How can I stop the sounds? Sounds are in a separate thread, and I don't know how to stop them.

2) If I continue pressing the key this code will play a lot of times the same sounds and this is not realistic (imagine a piano keyboard: if I press a key and I continue pressing it just one sounds (the firs) will play). How to solve this problem?
    I found a solution but now with threads I don't know how to do.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    th = new Thread(press));
    th.Start(new object[] { key, name });
}

private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    th = new Thread(leave);
    th.Start(new object[] { key, name });
}

private void press(object data)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    playSound(name);
}

private void leave(object data)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    stopSound(name);
}

private void playSound(string name)
{
    [...]   // Other code
    string url = Application.StartupPath + "\\notes\\" + name + ".wav";
    var sound = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

    sound.Open(new Uri(url));
    sound.play();
}

private void stopSound(string name)
{
    ???
}
```

Thank'you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the thread as a variable in the class so that it can be accessed whenever you want.
2. Use the Handled Property to prevent the event from being handled again

   `e.Handled = true;`

Comment: 1. How can I do that?

Comment: Umh I'm not understanding.. Can you please write the code for me?

Comment: I can't write code without seeing rest of the code. I cannot test in visual studio

Comment: The rest of the code is "useless" for this issues. I think you can write the code and solve at least one of this two problems. Or just try :)